# how to get more books in google book api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

while building a bookstore website using google book-api service i observed that google does not allow more than 40 books item to be requested and the code to fetch that is this

```js
appMainModule.controller("AfricanNovelsModule", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
   $scope.AfricanNovelsbookdetails = [];
    $scope.i = [];
    $scope.updateSearch = function () {
        //var search = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;
        var linkUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=African+folklore&maxResults=40&orderBy=newest';
        document.getElementById("ScriptSection").innerHTML = '<script id="widget" type="text/javascript" src="' + linkUrl + '" />';
        // getResponse();

        $http.get(linkUrl).then(function (res) {
            $scope.AfricanNovelsbookdetails = [];
            for (var i = 0, content = res.data.items.length; i < content; i++) {
                if (typeof res.data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks === undefined) {

                } else {
                    $scope.AfricanNovelsbookdetails.push(res.data.items[i]);
                    //console.log($scope.Comicbookdetails[i]);
                    //console.log($scope.Comicbookdetails[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0]);
                }
            }
            // console.log($scope.Comicbookdetails);
            $scope.i = generateRandom(res.data.items.length);
            // console.log($scope.i);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    $scope.updateSearch();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

but i want more than 40 books when i search, i would like to know if there are other alternatives i can use asides google book-api and what it is or if there is a solution fix for this

Answer (score 0):

The maximum allowable value for results to be retrieved is 40.

From https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using?hl=en

```
Maximum allowable value: maxResults=40.
```

You will need to send several requests (but check if there's a daily limit though).

Comment: yes i know they limit 40 but i want more than 40 and if i send several request with the same search query google book api  would still return the same 40